# Quick way to update an excel spreadsheet and upload changes made to excel into SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, excel

We have a department that has been working in an excel spreadsheet to track a major part of our business.  I'm sure this comes as no surprise to anyone, but the Excel Spreadsheet is a hot mess right now.  As we are working on implementing a long term solution for this data, I need a short term solution and I am hoping you might have some recommendations.  For the next two months, we need to identify problem areas in the spreadsheet (duplicate rows, missing data, etc) and as those problems are addressed in the excel spreadsheet, update the SQL server with those changes.

My thought is to schedule an SSIS to bring in the spreadsheet with changes nightly then run a stored proc to identify the problems, then run an SSRS to spit out a new excel spreadsheet for them to work on the next day.

Is there  a better way to do this that isn't going to take a ton of time/resources to get up and running?  I thought about Power Pivot and that would get the data out to them, but how would I upload the changes they make?

Anyway, is there a better quick solution to tide us over till we have our perm solution in place?  We are using a 2014 SQL Server and Microsoft Office 2016.

Thank you!

Comment: I think your idea is best. Short of a custom VBA solution that uses ADODB to interact with the database, but there is a whole host of difficulties to overcome to pull that off well.If you are comfortable with SSIS packages and Sql server procs, then leverage that knowledge. Marking this question as too broad for SO though.

Comment: in my opinion you could tell them to use MS Access as the interface to work and edit the data directly in the SQL server, instead the messy import export from excel.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use .NET with NPOI dlls https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi, grab the data from the spreadsheet, use classes, Generics and LINQ to clean the data and the upload it to SQL Server.